# Acumatica PXDataFieldAssign not setting logical field

Tags: c#, acumatica

I have a process that runs through the customer datafile and links it to the ARBalances file.

It compares Customer.CreditRule to see if it is set to a balance limit

If so, it compares the credit limit against the currentBalance of the customer. If the customer is over the limit, it sets a user defined DAC Field to true.

Everything seems to run, except it NEVER sets the flag to true. Even though it hits the logic, and it calls into PXDataFieldAssign() to set the value.

Meaning -- the line that calls:

```
PXDataFieldAssign("UsrCreditHoldActive", PXDbType.Bit, flagTrue)
```

**Does** get hit.

Yet, at the end of the run, **all records** are set to ***false***.

To start, I set all of the values of the new field to null using SQL in the MSSQL Manager:

```
Update Customer
SET [UsrCreditHoldActive] = null
Where CompanyID = 2
```

I run my Process Screen, and put break points at the lines where the PXDataFieldAssign gets called. I see it hitting the correct line for the customers who are over balance.

```
          using (PXTransactionScope CustomerTransactionScope = new PXTransactionScope())
          {
                // bool are Bits -- 1 == true, 0 == false;
                int flagTrue = 1;  int flagFalse = 0;

                foreach (var record in records)
                {
                    Customer currentCustomer = record as Customer;
                    var custExt = currentCustomer.GetExtension<ODCLEX.DAC.CustomerCHOLDExt>();
                    // is their CreditRule set to Balance Amount? If not, backordered = false
                    if (currentCustomer.CreditRule != "C")
                    {
                        var rslt = PXDatabase.Update<Customer>
                          (new PXDataFieldAssign("UsrCreditHoldActive", PXDbType.Bit, flagFalse));
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                          // does its balance exceed the credit limit?
                          // Get Customer's Balances
                          ARBalances balance = PXSelectReadonly<ARBalances,
                                  Where<ARBalances.customerID, Equal<Required<ARBalances.customerID>>>>
                                  .Select(onGraph, currentCustomer.BAccountID);
                          if (balance != null && balance.CurrentBal >= currentCustomer.CreditLimit)
                          {
                            var rslt = PXDatabase.Update<Customer>
                              (new PXDataFieldAssign("UsrCreditHoldActive", PXDbType.Bit, flagTrue));
                          }
                          else
                          {
                            var rslt = PXDatabase.Update<Customer>
                              (new PXDataFieldAssign("UsrCreditHoldActive", PXDbType.Bit, flagFalse));
                          }
                    }
                }  // foreach end loop
                CustomerTransactionScope.Complete();
          }  // End PXTransactionScope
        }); // PXLongOperation end brace
```

But when I run my SQL query to check it, I see ALL of the records have UsrCreditHoldActive set to 0.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

NVM. I should stop asking questions on SO after hours when my mind is frazzled.

The answer {in the light of day, after being properly caffienated} is that the UPDATE command requires restrictions -- otherwise, it updates all of the records in the database.

Without restrictions, the scope is ALL. The last record was setting it to 0, so it was The SQL Equivalent of:

```
Update Customer
SET [UsrCreditHoldActive] = 0
Where CompanyID = 2
```

So -- the way I wrote this -- the last one to write, determined the state of every customer.

So, my code needs to be this:

```
var rslt = PXDatabase.Update<Customer>
(new PXDataFieldAssign("UsrCreditHoldActive", PXDbType.Bit, flagTrue),
 new PXDataFieldRestrict(typeof(Customer.bAccountID).Name, PXDbType.Int, currentCustomer.BAccountID)
);
```